# Android: How to carry variable over different activities?

Tags: android-activity

First of all, I would like to say that I haven't found an article that answered my question.

I would like to do something(in no way is the following code) like, "if thisButtonIsPressed then thisVariable = 1" and carry that over to a different activity. Please tell me if I wasn't descriptive enough.

Edit: Please give me the code to do this.

Edit #2: I would appreciate it if someone told me another way to make a new page out of a lot(I'm making a page for each of the 118 elements!) without creating 118 activities.

Comment: check something called "Bundle"

Comment: see public static variables

Comment: I'm kind of new to android programming, so could you explain more?

Answer (score -1):

You should use a Bundle.
Here you have some info on how to use it:
[Passing Bundles Around Activities](http://www.remwebdevelopment.com/dev/a33/Passing-Bundles-Around-Activities.html)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.